# Updating php Session variable on image toggle

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to allow users to add/remove items from a shopping cart by simply clicking an image. I also want the image to change on click to show how many of this item has been purchased.

Finally, I want the cart to exist on a separate tab of the same page.

What I have so far is:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
...
...
<div style="display: block; width:1024px;">
<img id="image_id" src="image.png" width="110" height="110" style="margin-left:40px";>
<script>

$('#image_id').toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).attr('src','image1.png');
        <?php $_SESSION['cart']['image_id'] = 1; ?>
    },
    function() {
        $(this).attr('src','image2.png');
        <?php $_SESSION['cart']['image_id'] = 2; ?>
    },
    function() {
        $(this).attr('src','image3.png');
        <?php $_SESSION['cart']['image_id'] = 3; ?>
    },
    function() {
        $(this).attr('src','image.png');
    <?php// $_SESSION['cart']['image_id'] = 0; ?>
    }
);
</script>
...
...
</div>

<!-- Cart Tab -->

<div id="tab4" style="display:none; width:1024px; padding-top:40px;">

<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>

<?php
    if($_SESSION['cart']) {
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $itemname => $quantity)
        {
            if($quantity == 0) continue;
            $price = $_SESSION['items'][$itemname];
            $prod = $price*$quantity;
            $_SESSION['total'] += $prod;
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $itemname . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $price . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $quantity . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $prod . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $_SESSION['total'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }    
?>

<a href="#tab1">Continue Shopping</a>

</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that the image changes correctly (only changes when I click it and toggles through the four different images), but when I view the contents of the cart, it doesn't change. It executes all 4 php statements immediately. I know because if I remove the final toggle switch(where I reset the quantity to 0) and view the cart, it already shows that I have 3 items to be purchased before I even click once.

Any help would be appreciated. I am guessing I could also have constructed the images as form inputs, or hyperlinks that execute a script on click, but I have tried both approaches with no luck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't do that. You need to post that number you're setting it to (via AJAX) to a server side script that assigns it. Read a tutorial on AJAX - all you're doing here is redefining your session variable four times (sorry, three times - one is commented out)

Comment: Also you might want to consider getting to understand the difference between client and server side technologies altogther

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is executed in the browser, and php is executed on the server, before the page is served to the user.

Your PHP snippets are not executed when the javascript is called, rather they are executed on the server before the user even sees the page.

Instead of putting the PHP code directly in the javascript functions you need to use an AJAX call there that sends a request to the server.

That said, it looks like in this particular case it might be better to store the cart information in cookies rather than the session.

Comment: I have moved the php code into a separate file, and now I've tried both 
    XMLHttpRequest.open("GET","updatecart.php?action=add&id=1",true) 
and 
    $.ajax({ url: "updatecart.php?action=add&id=1", data: "", dataType: 'json' })

as drop-in replacements at the toggle point, but neither one seems to execute at all. Am I still missing something? Where should these calls go if I want them to execute on every click?? The toggle function seems only able to update the attributes of the image you are toggling, and can't really understand anything else.

Comment: you should put them in the click handler if you want them to be called whenever the images are clicked on (you can use the .click() jQuery method).